# column width jqgrid

Tags: model-view-controller, jqgrid

I am using jqgrid to display the data in 10 columns. There is one column PillName, we can store PillName as 100 caharacters in Database. While displaying in jqgrid, its displaying like in the following image:[image]

How to show the value in a proper way so that jqgrid dont get distorted. Ideally, it should break after some characters.

or It can show some 10 characters and then after that ........(dots)?

Kindly Help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that you have CSS conflicts between MVC and jqGrid. One sees problems already in the input field of the jqGrid pager. The problem for example can be fixed with additional CSS definition

```
input.ui-pg-input { width: auto; }
```

The close problem you have probably with `<td>` or `<tr>` elements. You can examine the styles of the grid cell with Developer Tools of Internet Explorer of Chrome oder with Firebug. You can also make a simple test and comment the whole MVC CSS or a large parts of the CSS. I suppose that the grid will looks OK after removing unneeded CSS declaration or including the fix like with the pager in the CSS of your projects.